# mod rewrite url automatically

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem for rewrite this url:

```
http://example.org/public/item.php?id=4
```

i id like to rewrite with htaccess file in:

```
http://example.org/public/item/4.php
```

this is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/

RewriteRule ^public/item/([^/]*)\.php$ /public/item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

that works only if i digit manually the previous url, but i lost all the style css, javascript file, and images, also i want to do this redirect seo url automatically.
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a condition if the requested filename(javascript, css, image, etc. files) actually exist not to rewrite the url,
So all you have to do is to add a condition before your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

check here the [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: i have to put in htaccess like this, RewriteCond %{query.js} -f? or all the absolute path?

Comment: No, you have to put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` like it is, because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is the actual filename you are requesting

Comment: i try do to this but when a reload the page, it give me 404

Comment: I don't understand if also i have to change the url in link inside the code php.